# In a ring of characteristic 2 every prime ideal is maximal ideal

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with  $1$ and $charR=2$.Then how can I show that every prime ideal in $R$ is a maximal ideal?

I was trying to show it a boolean ring but I could not.Please Help me.Thanks

Comment: This is very false. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: Boolean rings have both properties. Did you somehow mix the question up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false.

Take $F[x]$ where $F$ is the field of two elements.

The zero ideal is prime but not maximal.